# Removing similar rows from a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to remove similar rows from the csv file. Is there a function which can compare strings and discard them if there is an 80% match?

input data

```
    Identifier  StructureData
0   Entry ID    Structure Title
1   5O47        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with fructosyl-hydroxytyrosol
2   5FK8        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with Neo-erlose
3   5FK7        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with neokestose
4   5FMD        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with nystose
5   5FKC        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with Raffinose
6   5FIX        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with sucrose
7   6S82        Structure Of D80A-Fructofuranosidase From Xanthophyllomyces Dendrorhous Complexed With Tris-buffer molecule And hydroquinone
8   7ALJ        Structure of Drosophila Notch EGF domains 11-13
9   6YX5        Structure of DrrA from Legionella pneumophilia in complex with human Rab8a
10  3U75        Structure of E230A-fructofuranosidase from Schwanniomyces occidentalis complexed with fructosylnystose
11  5IFT        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 3-b-Galactopyranosyl glucose
12  5MGC        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 4-Galactosyl-lactose
13  5JUV        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 6-b-Galactopyranosyl galactose
14  5MGD        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 6-Galactosyl-lactose
15  5IHR        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH ALLOLACTOSE
```

output data

```
    Identifier  StructureData
0   Entry ID    Structure Title
1   5O47        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with fructosyl-hydroxytyrosol
2   7ALJ        Structure of Drosophila Notch EGF domains 11-13
3   6YX5        Structure of DrrA from Legionella pneumophilia in complex with human Rab8a
4   3U75        Structure of E230A-fructofuranosidase from Schwanniomyces occidentalis complexed with fructosylnystose
5   5IFT        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 3-b-Galactopyranosyl glucose
```

Comment: you are looking for something called *fuzzy matching*. There's a bunch of libraries for this, but `FuzzyWuzzy` is a good one. See [this article](https://www.activestate.com/blog/how-to-implement-fuzzy-matching-in-python/) for a good overview...

Answer (score 0):

There are several string similarity measures, here's one that is built in:

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def measure_similarity(x, y):
    return SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).ratio()

s1 = '5FMD        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with nystose'
s2 = '5FIX        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with sucrose'
sim = measure_similarity(s1, s2)

print(sim)
```

Result:

```
0.9528301886792453
```

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for something called fuzzy matching. There's a bunch of libraries for this, but FuzzyWuzzy is a good one. See this [article](https://www.activestate.com/blog/how-to-implement-fuzzy-matching-in-python/) for a good overview...

Note that the code below does not meet your expectations completely as it includes row 7 from your data, as the difference is more than 80% compared to the previous rows.

```py
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


data = """Identifier  StructureData
Entry ID    Structure Title
5O47        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with fructosyl-hydroxytyrosol
5FK8        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with Neo-erlose
5FK7        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with neokestose
5FMD        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with nystose
5FKC        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with Raffinose
5FIX        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with sucrose
6S82        Structure Of D80A-Fructofuranosidase From Xanthophyllomyces Dendrorhous Complexed With Tris-buffer molecule And hydroquinone
7ALJ        Structure of Drosophila Notch EGF domains 11-13
6YX5        Structure of DrrA from Legionella pneumophilia in complex with human Rab8a
3U75        Structure of E230A-fructofuranosidase from Schwanniomyces occidentalis complexed with fructosylnystose
5IFT        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 3-b-Galactopyranosyl glucose
5MGC        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 4-Galactosyl-lactose
5JUV        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 6-b-Galactopyranosyl galactose
5MGD        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 6-Galactosyl-lactose
5IHR        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH ALLOLACTOSE"""

result = []
for line_data in data.splitlines():
    maxvalue = 0
    for line_result in result:
        maxvalue = max(maxvalue, fuzz.ratio(line_data, line_result))
    if maxvalue < 80:
        result.append(line_data)


for line in result:
    print(line)
```

output

```
Identifier  StructureData
Entry ID    Structure Title
5O47        Structure of D80A-fructofuranosidase from Xanthophyllomyces dendrorhous complexed with fructosyl-hydroxytyrosol
6S82        Structure Of D80A-Fructofuranosidase From Xanthophyllomyces Dendrorhous Complexed With Tris-buffer molecule And hydroquinone
7ALJ        Structure of Drosophila Notch EGF domains 11-13
6YX5        Structure of DrrA from Legionella pneumophilia in complex with human Rab8a
3U75        Structure of E230A-fructofuranosidase from Schwanniomyces occidentalis complexed with fructosylnystose
5IFT        STRUCTURE OF E298Q-BETA-GALACTOSIDASE FROM ASPERGILLUS NIGER IN COMPLEX WITH 3-b-Galactopyranosyl glucose
```

---

**EDIT**

To apply this to a CSV file, use the CSV DictReader/DictWriter and only compare the `Structure Title` column. You'll need to change the delimiter and perhaps the quote character to suit the actual file you have. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) for that part.

```py
import csv
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz


tracker = []
with open("infile.csv", newline="") as infile:
    with open("outfile.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(infile, delimiter=";")
        writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames, delimiter=";")
        writer.writeheader()
        for row in reader:
            maxvalue = 0
            for existing in tracker:
                maxvalue = max(maxvalue, fuzz.ratio(row["Structure Title"], existing))
            if maxvalue < 80:
                tracker.append(row["Structure Title"])           
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: thanks! I want to take input as a csv file and compare the elements from the 'StructureData only' and then delete the similar rows from 'StructureData'.

Comment: see my updated answer